# Missing Invantive.Data assembly

Tags: exact-online, invantive-bridge

When using the Invantive Bridge for Exact Online, Visual Studio complaints that even after installation of Invantive Bridge, that the references are missing.

How can I find the references of Invantive.Data namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can best reference the nuget package `Invantive.Bridge.Developers`. It takes care of everything.

Alternative is to include the references all yourself (there are a lot since all 50-60 platforms are included) chosing from `c:\program files (x86)\invantive software\invantive bridge`. New releases automatically add this one to your Visual Studio 2017 folder.

Please also note that this only works with 4.7 framework and netstandard 2.0.

Comment: Where can I find the Invantive.Bridge.Developers on nuget.org?